# Facebook SDK in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-emulator, android-facebook

I am using Facebook SDK for android as external library.I am able to login through facebook.But when I want to share an image and  app has not logged in thru facebook, I am trying to login but in that case I am getting exception and getting access token as null.Please help

W/com.facebook.Session(15670): Should not pass a read permission (email) to a request for publish or manage authorization
 W/com.facebook.Session(15670): Should not pass a read permission (read_friendlists) to a request for publish or manage authorization

Please find the code:

```
String[] permissions = { "email",
            "user_birthday",
            "publish_stream",
            "user_checkins",
            "friends_checkins",
            "read_friendlists",
            "publish_checkins",
            "publish_actions" };
     final static int AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 0;
facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                                    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                                    facebook.authorize(getActivity(), permissions, AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE,
                                            new DialogListener() {


                                                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                                    System.err.println("Inside oncomplete");
                                                    //getProfileInformation();


                                                }


                                                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                                                    System.err.println(error.toString()+ "Facebook.authorize Error: ");

                                                    try {
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                                    }
                                                    dialog=null;
                                                }


                                                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                                    System.err.println(e.toString()+ "Facebook.authorize DialogError: ");
                                                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                                                            "Facebook.authorize DialogError: "
                                                                    + e.toString());
                                                    try {
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                                    }
                                                    dialog=null;
                                                }


                                                public void onCancel() {
                                                    System.err.println("Facebook authorization canceled");
                                                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                                                            "Facebook authorization canceled");
                                                    try {
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                                    }
                                                    dialog=null;
                                                }
                                            });

                                }

                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First Download [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) Facebbok SDK and include it in your project as library project.

In your activity,where you want to share the image ::

```
private static Bitmap b;
private static Facebook mFacebook;
private static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String[] permissions = {"photo_upload" };
final static int AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 0;
```

In **onCreate()** initialize this variables ::

```
if (Constant.FACEBOOK_APP_ID == null)
 {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be "
                        + "specified before running this example: see FbAPIs.java");
        return;
 }

mHandler=new Handler();
mFacebook = new Facebook(Constant.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE: 
        {
        mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

onButtonClick from where you are going to share a Image ::

```
if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) 
{
    mFacebook.authorize(TabNoteActivity.this, permissions, AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE, new LoginDialogListener());
}
else
{
     Bundle params = new Bundle();
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     Utils.b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);//Here I am convert the JPG image into bitmap using declaring method in the Utils class 
     byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
     params.putString (Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
     params.putString ("message"," Facebook App Testing");
     params.putByteArray("picture",byteArray);
     mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params,"POST", new PhotoUploadListener(),null);
}


    public class PhotoUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener
    {
        //@Override
        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) 
        {

           mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
           {
            // @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"Image has been shared Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          });
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```